# Insert xml into a pdf

Tags: java, xml, pdf, itext

I need to insert an .xml in a .pdf (and then later digitally sign all).
The implementation guide that I'm following tell me to insert my xml data populating the structure called "XFAResources", as you can see in this example (my data is contained within the ClinicalDocument block):

```
<Xfa: datasets xmlns: xfa = "http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/">
   <Xfa: date>
     <ClinicalDocument xmlns = "urn: hl7-org: v3" ...>
      ...
     </ClinicalDocument>
   </Xfa: date>
</Xfa: datasets>
```

Could someone give me some information about how can I do it?
Both the xml that the PDF was generated by me, the second using iText5.

--- Updating ---

My need is to perform the insertion, injection, an XML in a PDF, I have to do this work for a thesis project and the only “restriction” that was given to me is the programming language, Java precisely, for the rest I have total freedom.

So I, using Eclipse, I created / saved my XML and using iText I created / saved PDF, which is not an XFA form, with the content and formatting I decided, now I have to make an injection.

The teacher has also informed me this morning that it is not necessary the final signature of the file.

Can you then recommend a way to simply make an injection? I believe that through iText is possible but unfortunately I can not understand how.

Thank you in advance for availability.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "injection"? Is the content to be displayed on the PDF pages or does it suffice to have the file as an attachment? (In the latter case I would assume this to be merely a very small part of the project as that is a trivial task.)

Comment: @mkl Is exactly, in fact this point is only a small part of my thesis work. I have a "CDA", that is a clinical document in XML format, and I must add it in a PDF that contains substantially the same information, the purpose of the first is to be processed by a machine while that of the second to be read by a person.

As said, I can choose how to fix it, but I have to try to do it in efficient way.

Comment: For attachments you might want to look [here on the iText site](http://developers.itextpdf.com/tags/attachments) - Chose the articles for your iText version of choice there, iText5 or iText7.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try to use this method. I hope goes well to the teacher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to `XFAResources`. There is no such thing as `XFAResources` in ISO-32000-1 (aka the current PDF specification). `XFAResources` was introduced in one of the early drafts of ISO-32000-2 (aka PDF 2.0, to be released later this year), but it was removed during the development of the new specification. It's not in the FDIS (Final Draft International Standard), which means it will never be part of an official specification.

In short: the *implementation guide that you are following* is wrong. It would help if (1.) you shared that implementation guide, and (2.) asked its author to adapt it so that it reflects official standards.

As for your problem:

1. I assume that you have an XFA form that was created using Adobe LiveCycle Designer, and that you want to inject XML into this form. This question has been asked answered before: [How to fill out a pdf file programmatically? (Dynamic XFA)](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-fill-out-pdf-file-programmatically-dynamic-xfa)
2. You want to sign the form, and signing XFA forms is described in PAdES-5: *PAdES for XML Content – Profiles for XAdES signatures of XML content in PDF files.* This was implemented in iText, but unfortunately, I don't know of any other implementations. As far as I remember, Adobe has a completely different implementation which makes it impossible to verify a PAdES-5 created with iText in Adobe Reader (please check with Adobe if this is still true). No other viewer supports PAdES-5, and XFA will be deprecated in PDF 2.0 (which significantly reduces the chance that any vendor will invest in further development).
3. You don't want to sign the *form*, but you want to sign the *flattened form*. In that case, you first need to convert the XFA into real PDF. An XFA form is nothing but XML wrapped inside a PDF structure, and you need software such as Adobe LiveCycle ES or iText's XFA Worker to convert that XML to regular PDF. This is very specialized software that is not available as open source software. Given the fact that XFA will be deprecated, there is very little chance that anyone will ever do the effort to create such software as open source software. However, if you buy either Adobe LiveCycle ES or iText's XFA Worker, you will be able to create a document that can be signed using a PAdES-2 (ISO-32000-1 style) or PAdES-3 (new in ISO-32000-2) signature.

You asked your fellow subscribers on StackOverflow *"Could someone give me some information about how can I do it?"* I hope the above information already points you towards the relevant specifications (ISO-32000-1 and -2, PAdES-2, -3, and -5), but unfortunately, it is impossible to give you a code sample, as your question isn't accurate enough for the following reasons:

- Your assumption that you need to populate a structure called `XFAResources` is based on an implementation guide that refers to a structure that never made it into an official standard.
- You aren't entirely clear about the nature of the template: is it really an XFA form? If so, why? XFA forms are about to become obsolete.
- You aren't entirely clear about the nature of the signed result: does the document need to remain an XFA form (PAdES-5), or is it OK for the document to be flattened?

Comment: First of all thank you for the answer. You are absolutely right, unfortunately I have based on a wrong Implementation Guide.


I'm afraid I did not explain well my problem, I edited the question to try to better explain my problem

Comment: I don't see any requirement to use XFA, so if I were you, I'd stay away from XFA as far as possible and I'd use XFDF instead. See http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-save-xfdf-file-pdf-file for a complete example (all your work is done if you follow that example). Extra bonus: a filled out AcroForm can easily be signed.

Comment: I do not want to use a XFA, indeed for the reasons that you said I would avoid it. However, I'm not sure that its solution is what I need. My PDF is static with the defined data, I do not need to compile it using the XML. I have only put it inside, probably the solution is simpler than what you be thinking. Perhaps as kml says is sufficient to attach the XML file to PDF.